# Saving data from textboxes into text file

Tags: c#, file, button, text, save

I am trying to write a program to me should be a lot easier than it is proving.
I have a form with text boxes that asks the user to enter their details e.g. Name, Address etc.. What I am trying to achieve is to save the data from the text boxes into a .txt file when the user hits the save button.

I am able to create the file but the data will not save into the file. 
I have posted my code below, and any help you may have will be greatly appreciated.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string file_name = "e:\\test1.txt";

    System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
    objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file_name, true);

    objWriter.Write(txtName.Text);
    objWriter.Write(txtAddress.Text);
    objWriter.Write(txtEmail.Text);
    objWriter.Write(txtPhone.Text);

    MessageBox.Show("Details have been saved");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more practical to use `using` at the beginning of the code line where StreamWriter is present. This is to ensure data are `Disposed`, you'll need this to unlock the data from the stream.

When writing data:

```
 using (StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter("test1.txt"))
{
    objWriter.Write(txtName.Text);
    objWriter.Write(txtAddress.Text);
    objWriter.Write(txtEmail.Text);
    objWriter.Write(txtPhone.Text);

    MessageBox.Show("Details have been saved");
}
```

When reading saved data, let's use a listbox just to have an example:

```
  foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("test1.txt"))
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(line);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, your code for reading the data works for me.

Comment: no problem my friend. maybe you can accept my answer so this thread can be marked as solved. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is a good practice to wrap local variables implementing `IDisposable` into the `using` statement:

```
using (StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(file_name, true))
{
    objWriter.Write(txtName.Text);
    objWriter.Write(txtAddress.Text);
    objWriter.Write(txtEmail.Text);
    objWriter.Write(txtPhone.Text);
}
```

This also has a positive side effect: the stream is flushed and closed right after execution of the `using` statement.

*Suggestion:* Consider using `WriteLine` instead of `Write`, because probably you need a delimiter between string values.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I decided on the WriteLine instead of write.

Answer (score 1):

Call [`StreamWriter.Flush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx) method after you done:

```
objWriter.Flush();
```

> Clears all buffers for the current writer and causes any buffered data to be written to the underlying stream.

You could also do this using [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var line = string.Join(" ", txtName.Text, txtAddress.Text, txtEmail.Text,txtPhone.Text);
File.WriteAllText(file_name, line);
```